# Issue with the "Even Digits" problem from Round A of 2018 in Google Kickstart

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am currently practicing on Google Kickstart competition and I am currently working on the [Even Digits problem from Round A of 2018](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000050edf/00000000000510ed).

I have created the following algorithm and when I test it, it works just great. But the problem is that when I submit it to the platform and press the "Attempt" button, it shows that **my output is not correct**.

I retried testing it using larger and more complex numbers but I just *cannot find what is the case*.

> **Problem Description:**
>
> Supervin has a unique calculator. This calculator only has a display, a plus button, and a minus button. Currently, the integer **N** is displayed on the calculator display.
>    Pressing the plus button increases the current number displayed on the calculator display by 1. Similarly, pressing the minus button decreases the current number displayed on the calculator display by 1. The calculator does not display any leading zeros. For example, if *100* is displayed on the calculator display, pressing the minus button once will cause the calculator to display *99*.
>    Supervin does not like odd digits, because he thinks they are "odd". Therefore, he wants to display an integer with only even digits in its decimal representation, using only the calculator buttons. Since the calculator is a bit old and the buttons are hard to press, he wants to use a minimal number of button presses.
>    Please help Supervin to determine the minimum number of button presses to make the calculator display an integer with no odd digits.
>   **Input**
>   The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, **T**. **T** test cases follow. 
>   Each begins with one line containing an integer **N**: 
>   the integer initially displayed on Supervin's calculator.

**Here is my code:**

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var SCount = Console.ReadLine();
  long Count = Convert.ToInt64(SCount);

  for (long i = 0; i < Count; i++)
  {
    var val = Console.ReadLine();
    long l = Convert.ToInt64(val);

    Console.WriteLine("Case #{0}: {1}", i + 1, Slover4(l));
  }
}

public static long Slover4(double N)
{
  char[] odds = { '1', '3', '5', '7', '9' };

  double presses_p = 0;
  double PN = N;
  double presses_n = 0;
  double NN = N;

  double pdegits = -1;
  for (int i = PN.ToString().Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    pdegits += 1;

    //2110
    //2018 EVEN EVEN (ODD EVEN)  ---->
    //11   ODD OOD               <----
    //1    ODD                   ---->
    //42   EVEN EVEN             XXXXX 6969 1 | 6970 30 | 7000 -200 | 6800

    #region Positives
    if (i > 0 && odds.Contains(PN.ToString()[i]) &&
        odds.Contains(PN.ToString()[i - 1])) // ODD - ODD 
    {
      var val = int.Parse(string.Concat(PN.ToString()[i - 1], PN.ToString()[i]));
      var lv = int.Parse(PN.ToString()[i].ToString());
      //15 17  19
      //5  3   1
      presses_p += (5 - (lv - 5)) * Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
      PN += (5 - (lv - 5)) * Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
    }
    else if (i != 0 &&
             !odds.Contains(PN.ToString()[i - 1]) &&
             odds.Contains(PN.ToString()[i])) // EVEN - ODD 
    {
      presses_p += Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
      PN += Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
    }
    else if (i != 0 && 
             odds.Contains(PN.ToString()[i - 1])) // ODD - EVEN
    {
      var val = int.Parse(string.Concat(PN.ToString()[i - 1], PN.ToString()[i]));
      var lv = int.Parse(PN.ToString()[i].ToString());

      //10 12 14 16 18
      //10  8  6  4  2  ->

      //10 12 14|
      //2 4  6 |
      presses_p += (10 - lv) * Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
      PN += (10 - lv) * Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
    }
    else if (i == 0 && 
             odds.Contains(PN.ToString()[i])) // ODD Only
    {
      presses_p += Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
      PN += Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Negatives 

    if (i > 0 && 
        odds.Contains(NN.ToString()[i]) && 
        odds.Contains(NN.ToString()[i - 1])) // ODD - ODD 
    {
      var val = int.Parse(string.Concat(NN.ToString()[i - 1], NN.ToString()[i]));
      var lv = int.Parse(NN.ToString()[i].ToString());
      //11 13 15 17 19
      //3  5  7  9  11
      presses_n += (3 + (lv - 1)) * Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
      NN -= (3 + (lv - 1)) * Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
    }
    else if (i != 0 &&
             !odds.Contains(NN.ToString()[i - 1]) &&
             odds.Contains(NN.ToString()[i])) // EVEN - ODD 
    {
      presses_n += Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
      NN -= Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
    }
    else if (i != 0 &&
             odds.Contains(NN.ToString()[i - 1])) // ODD - EVEN
    {
      var val = int.Parse(string.Concat(NN.ToString()[i - 1], NN.ToString()[i]));
      var lv = int.Parse(NN.ToString()[i].ToString());

      //10 12 14 16 18     
      //2  4  6  8  10  <-

      presses_n += (2 + lv) * Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
      NN -= (2 + lv) * Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
    }
    else if (i == 0 &&
             odds.Contains(NN.ToString()[i])) // ODD Only
    {
      presses_n += Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
      NN -= Math.Pow(10, pdegits);
    }
    #endregion
  }

  //$"P:{presses_p} - N - {presses_n}";
  return presses_p < presses_n ? (long)presses_p : (long)presses_n;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide the link or, better, the link and the problem's description

Comment: Is https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000050edf/00000000000510ed the right link?

Comment: Yes it's the right link

Comment: I added the problem description

Comment: Debugging other people's code is *hard*, especially cryptic code like this with only sparse comments. I don't expect anyone will put the effort into finding the flaw(s) in your code. As a general rule, it's well worth explaining your algorithm in the comments at the top, and then in the code highlighting which bit implements which bit of the algorithm, both for people like us helping you, for your coworkers, and for your future self!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK then, let's start from *degenerated cases*:

1. If we are given *all even digits* number (e.g. `2048`) we return `0`
2. If it is the *last digit* only which is odd (e.g. `64087`) we return `1`

Now let `left` be the index of the leftmost odd digit (`leftDigit`) e.g.

```
 2480032581
      ^
      left = 5 (since 2, 4, 8, 0, 0 are even)
      leftDigit = 3
```

We can turn the initial number either into (by pressing <kbd>-</kbd> button)

```
 2480028888
```

Or (by pressing <kbd>+</kbd> button) into

```
 2480040000
```

Finally, we can compare both possibilities and take the one which requiers *fewer presses*:

```
 "-"  wants 2480032581 - 2480028888 == 3693 presses
 "+"  wants 2480040000 - 2480032581 == 7419 presses
```

Pressing `-` is a better strategy for the given number and so we return `3693`.
Please, note, that if `leftDigit` is `9` we shall stick to `"-"` presses (and ignore `+` strategy).

**C# Code:**

```
private static long Solution(string value) {
  int left = -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) {
    if ((value[i] - '0') % 2 != 0) {
      left = i;

      break;
    }
  }

  if (left < 0)
    return 0;                 // All even digits number 
  else if (left == value.Length - 1)
    return 1;                 // The very last digit is the only odd one

  long initial = long.Parse(value.Substring(left));
  int leftDigit = value[left] - '0';

  if (leftDigit == 9)
    return initial - long.Parse(new string('8', value.Length - left));

  long plus = 
    long.Parse((leftDigit + 1).ToString() + new string('0', value.Length - left - 1)) - 
    initial;

  long minus = initial - 
    long.Parse((leftDigit - 1).ToString() + new string('8', value.Length - left - 1));

  return plus < minus ? plus : minus;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new[] {
    "42",
    "11",
    "1",
    "2018"
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,6} -> {Solution(test),3}"));
```

**Outcome:**

```
    42 ->   0
    11 ->   3
     1 ->   1
  2018 ->   2
```

Comment: You can expand your second degenerative case a bit -- if only the final digit of a multi-digit number is odd (i.e. `left == value.Length - 1`), then the result is 1. Not that it has any practical impact...

Comment: @canton7: You are quite right, thank you! I've edited the answer

Comment: (For the record, I ran this code and submitted the results to the Google Kickstart page, and it passed)

Comment: @greybeard: how could the left*most* odd digit be preceded by an odd digit?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: in case the string has '9xxxx' then you are subtracting from '8xxxx' ? I don't know c# so wondering how this will handle 2999 case and 9888 case?

Comment: @newbie_old: `9xxxx` should be turned into `88888` (`-` strategy), alternative approach - `200000` is always too expensive. `2999` will be turned into `2888` and `9888` into `8888`